# How Do I Make A Flip Animation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My animation currently animates my new view to come in from the bottom.  I would rather have it do a horizontal flip instead.

How can I edit my code to result in this?  Thanks.

```
-(void) aboutButtonPressed
{
    [aboutView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:aboutView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        [aboutView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    }];
}
```

Update:

```
@interface AboutViewController : UIViewController {
    NSMutableArray *array1;
    NSMutableArray *array2;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *aboutTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navBar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *array1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *array2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the flip animation you are desiring comes from `presentModalViewController:animated:` which can be found in the [UIViewController Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW49)

What you would want is to turn your aboutView into a AboutViewController:

```
-(void) aboutButtonPressed
{
    AboutViewController *viewController = [[AboutViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AboutViewController" bundle:nil];

    viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    viewController.delegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];

    [viewController release];
}
```

Comment: Ok so lets say I add the method `- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated`.  What would I put inside the method? I'm kinda confused how to tell it what view to push.

Comment: I edited my answer to show code for using a UIViewController versus a UIView. However I think that Ken Pepisa's answer may be more of what you are specifically looking for. +1

Comment: Thanks Dredful!  If you don't mind, could you tell me how to dismiss this modal view as well? Thanks again!

Comment: No Prob. Inside the AboutViewController code you will want to call [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; at whatever point you wish to get rid of the AboutViewController. The key is that the presented UIViewController usually dismisses itself.

Comment: I have a barButtonItem that is in IB, but I can't connect with my method do dismissView.  When I link it, it only lets me connect to First Responder and not File's Owner.  Any ideas why?

Comment: Is the  barButtonitem's Referenceing Outlet connected to File's Owner?

Comment: Yes it is.  I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: I'm far from an Interface Builder expert but is the base View referencing outlet wire to File's Owner?

Comment: Yes it is, everything else is working as expected.  I don't mind doing it in code but it didnt work for some reason.  I usually use this code `UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addToRoutine)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    [addButton release];` but it didn't work for this case.  the `navigationItem` was not found, I declared a `UINavigationBar *navBar`.

Comment: Ok. Without seeing it, I think you need to declare IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navigationItem; and declare a Reference Outlet between the nib and navigationItem. Perhaps when you were back using the UIView, you were referencing a navigationItem that already existed in the superview? With a presentModalViewController:animated: you are starting from scratch in that presented UIViewController.

Comment: hey dredful, i've updated my original question with the header code I have

Comment: Well, our apps rarely ever use UINavigationBar but I am pretty certain you need @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationBarIten *navigationItem; I think I understand the confusion. You are not working with a UINavigationController. You did a presentModalViewController:animated: not a pushViewController:animated:

Comment: This is why I wonder if Ken Pespisa's answer is a better solution for you. That way everything stays in the navigationController you were already likely working with.

Comment: Thanks dreful, i've made a new question relating to this problem. thanks.

Comment: hey I am not able to writeuse "viewController.delegate = self;"
please some one tell

Answer (score 1):

Use the method:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:]
```

for example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
    delay:0.0 
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
    animations:^{
            [aboutView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,
            self.view.frame.size.height)];
    }
    completion:nil]
```

More on that in the UIView docs:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html